# View hierarchy of UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiviewcontroller

In my ContainerViewController i added scrollView as a subview.And in that scrollview i added ImageViewController's view as a subview. Now should i add the ImageViewController as a child view controller to the ContainerViewController?

Comment: What are you trying to do. Can you explain more in detail.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept for "child view controller". You only need to set the hierarchy for the views, and let the view controllers control the view's behavior.

Comment: its there in ios 5.0 http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add the `UIImageView` again for the basic `UIViewController`.

hierarchically, you created the first `UIViewController` and for its `UIView` you added the `UIScrollView` as a subview, and you added an `UIImageView` to the `UIScrollView`.

this is perfect.

**try to imagine them as a pair of shoes** (`UIImageView`) **in a box** (`UIScrollView`) **what is in your drawer** (`UIViewController`).

you won't need to put the pair of shoes into your drawer again if you put the box with the shoes into the drawer before; because your pair of shoes are already in the drawer, inside a box.

Comment: I want to add a ImageViewController which is subclass of UIViewController. not a UIImageView.

Comment: in that case you have to add the `UIView` property of the inherited class of `UIViewController` to the `UIScrollView` as subview. no matter what the current name is the inherited class, the process and the logic are same.